# Print multiple times in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

```
    from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
    #simplified_scrapy is framework for extrcting data
    xml = utils.getFileContent('check_in.xml')
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
    #SimplifiedDoc is a library for parsing data such as HTML and XML
    
    nodes = doc.select('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ').children
    print (nodes.tag)
    
    for x in nodes:
        print((doc.select('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ')['Version']),(doc.select('com:Source')))
              
    
    Here is my output:-
    4.000 {'tag': 'com:Source', 'AirlineVendorID': 'CM'}
    4.000 {'tag': 'com:Source', 'AirlineVendorID': 'CM'}
    4.000 {'tag': 'com:Source', 'AirlineVendorID': 'CM'}
    4.000 {'tag': 'com:Source', 'AirlineVendorID': 'CM'}
    4.000 {'tag': 'com:Source', 'AirlineVendorID': 'CM'}
    4.000 {'tag': 'com:Source', 'AirlineVendorID': 'CM'}
```

Here is my python code in which I want to print only once, but when I run this it gives me output which prints multiple times. I want to print only once.
Can anyone help me out why this print multiple times instead of once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your `print()` inside `for x in nodes:` it will print for every `x` in `nodes`.
Just remove your for loop, you're not even using `x` in your loop.

Comment: Thanx, I got your point. Do you have any idea how to use loop here as I have many parameters to print?

Comment: Your for loop has to involve 'x' in some way, but with the current information I can't suggest more than replacing 'doc' with 'x' like @Benjamin Philip already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Like what Adamantoisetortoise said, you are printing in a loop.
Get rid of this:

```py
for x in nodes:
        print((doc.select('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ')['Version']),(doc.select('com:Source')))
```

From what I understand, You are trying to extract some information from nodes
You could try this:

```py
for x in nodes:
        print((x.select('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ')['Version']),(x.select('com:Source')))
```

But this may not work as I don't know what data you are working with.

Comment: Above loop is not working, throwing error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. here I am try to parse SOAP XML and extract information from it.

Comment: As I said, I don't know what data you are working on. Hence I cannot say of sure...

Comment: If there may be no value, the error will not be reported in this way:  (x.select('air:EDS_AirCheckInRQ>Version()')